# Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'string'

Tags: angular, typescript, promise

Here I set the function `toBase64()`

```
export function toBase64(file:File) {
   
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        

        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        reader.onload=()=> resolve(reader.result);
        reader.onerror=(error) =>reject(error);
    })
```

it shows that the type of `reader.result` is
`string | ArrayBuffer | null`, however, when I need to use the response.

```
export class InputImgComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }
  imageBase64!:string;
  @Output()
  onImageSelected = new EventEmitter<File>();


  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
  change(event:any){
    if(event.target.files.length>0) {
      const file:File= event.target.files[0];
      toBase64(file).then((value)=>this.imageBase64=value ); 
    }
```

it said the `result type is unknown`, and I set `imageBase64` to string, `Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'string'`.

That's really weird, how can I solve this problem, I only need the string result.

Comment: You should give `toBase64` a return type annotation

Answer (score 4):

You haven't specified the type of `Promise` returned by your function, so it defaults to `Promise<unknown>`. `Promise` is a generic type, so a promise of a string is a `Promise<string>`.

You can either annotate this on the constructor of the promise, or on the return type of the function and Typescript will infer it for you.

```
export function toBase64(file:File) {
    return new Promise<string>((resolve,reject) => {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        // the docs say that result should always be a string, but double-check for future-proofing
        reader.onload = (ev) => typeof reader.result === "string" ? resolve(reader.result) : reject("Unexpected type received from FileReader");
        reader.onerror = (error) => reject(error);
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    })
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use type assertion to specify the type for `value` in the lambda callback. Currently it is `unknown` by default.

```
((value:string) => this.imageBase64=value)
```

Comment: This answer does not address the root of the problem, which is that `toBase64` has an incorrect return type (`Promise<unknown>`).